# Site Loads Fast First Time but Slows Down Significantly with each Reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with a single-page web application I am building.  The first load in any session (i.e., first time that day) the page loads almost instantly; 1 second or so, and the spinning CSS-only page loader works beautifully.  Then with every subsequent F5 reload it slows down significantly - it starts taking 10 - 15 seconds and the page loader gets all glitchy like the browser is really struggling.

A little background, the site is JavaScript and Jquery; no framework.  The server is fine, my computer is fine, my internet connection is super fast.  It's a code problem.  I work on the site everyday and things were fine until a couple of weeks ago when this started.

I have read articles on JavaScript "memory leaks" and wonder if maybe that is it.  I've also read some articles like "top 10 things that are slowing your site down" and none of what they suggest really applies.  The site is slimmed down and other than Jquery and Google fonts it is not running all over the internet downloading dozens of libraries on each load.

This is a large application with many thousands of lines of code.  If someone wants me to paste a specific piece of code I am happy to do it, but if I pasted the entire site it would break the internet.

I am using Google Chrome Developer mode.  The problem persists even if  get out of developer mode and let the site cache like a normal user.

I'm pulling my hair out and would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Are you using version control? If so, check out older versions of your site until the problem no longer exists, and then move forward in time until the problem appears, and carefully review the changes that were made that might be contributing to the problem.

Comment: We simply cannot help you without either more information or code. If you could link to the site that would be a help, or if you could build a *minimal reproducible example* (though this would probably imply that you could locate the culprit) that would be great.

Comment: One thing to check for: Any weird session cookies/storage that seem to accumulates at any point in the app, such that every time your app loads, its looping over the values and doing the thing multiple times (exponentially)

Comment: Appreciate it folks, I'm fairly new at this, one year in.  I was hoping this would sound like a classic sign of XYZ but I guess not.  I back up the site every day but only keep a week's worth of backups.